# How do I use cin.getline() in this program so it can read spaces?

Tags: c++

How would I use cin.getline() in this code to have the program take a space as input when typing the name of the item?

This is what I want my code to be able to do:
Using dynamic array, write a program that allows the user to enter the number of groceries purchased and the price of each item. The program then outputs the total cost of groceries,including tax of 8%.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct lineItem {
    string groceries;
    int quantity;
    double pricePerEach;
};

double sumPrice(lineItem *list, int size);

void printGroceries(lineItem *list, int size);


int main () {
    double salesTax;
    double subTotal, totalPrice;
    int i, numOfItems;

    cout << "Enter number of grocery items: ";
    cin >> numOfItems;
    cout << endl;

    lineItem *receipt;      //or auto *receipt = new lineItem[numOfItems];
    receipt = new lineItem[numOfItems];

    cout << "Enter the name, quantity, and price of item: " << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < numOfItems; i++)
        cin >> receipt[i].groceries >> receipt[i].quantity >> receipt[i].pricePerEach;

    subTotal = sumPrice(receipt, numOfItems);

    cout << "Sub Total: $" << subTotal << endl;

    salesTax = .08 * subTotal;
    totalPrice = subTotal + salesTax;

    cout << "Sales Tax at 8% : $" << salesTax << endl;
    cout << "Total Price: $" << totalPrice << endl;

    printGroceries(receipt, numOfItems);
    sumPrice(receipt, numOfItems);

    delete [] receipt;

    return 0;
}

double sumPrice(lineItem *list, int size) {
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum = sum + (list[i].quantity * list[i].pricePerEach);
    }
    return sum;
}

void printGroceries(lineItem *list, int size) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << (i + 1) << ":" << list[i].groceries << endl;
    }
}
```

I tried to do this but it didn't work. Ideally, I'd like the prompt the input like below. I am just having trouble formatting it correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
for (i = 0; i < numOfItems; i++) {
        cout << "Item name: ";
        cin.getline(receipt[i].groceries,numOfItems);

        cout << "\tQuantity: ";
        cin.getline(receipt[i].quantity,numOfItems);

        cout << "\tPrice: $";
        cin.getline(receipt[i].pricePerEach,numOfItems);
    }
```

Comment: To read into a `std::string` use a different `getline`: `std::getline(cin, receipt[i].groceries);` [Documentation for `std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). The `cin.getline` variant [only knows how to read into `char` arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

Comment: Always read the docs first: [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). It shows examples on the usage.

Comment: Thank you! I read the docs first, but I was still confused on how to do it with the use of structs. Is this what you mean? for (i = 0; i < numOfItems; i++) { cout << "Item name: "; getline(cin, receipt[i].groceries); cout << "\tQuantity: "; getline(cin, receipt[i].quantity); //this is giving me an error saying "no matching function for call to 'getline' cout << "\tPrice: $"; getline(cin, receipt[i].pricePerEach); //same here }